# Modifier causing "invalid opcode" in TestRPC

Tags: solidity, testrpc, testing, mocha

I have a token and crowdfund that works fine, except in tests. I can use all the methods, but I get invalid opcode on any of them that have a call to another contract that has a modifier on that function.

For instance, if I have `ContractA`, `ContractB`, and `ContractC`, and I call `ContractA` from `addressA`, and `ContractA` has a modifier to only accept calls from `addressA`, and all the functions on `ContractA` call out to `ContractB` and the functions on `ContractB` all have modifiers to only accept calls from `ContractA`.

This works great in practice, breaks when I run my tests. If I remove the modifiers, the tests run. Is this a known bug? I can confirm the modifiers all use `msg.sender` - perhaps testrpc isn't forwarding this correctly?

Comment: TestRPC forwards msg.sender correctly. Please include your deployment scripts as there may be sth wrong with the way you deploy your contracts to test network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I finally debugged it. In my tests I was using Token.address syntax to get an address when I should have been using my tokenInstance.address variable that returns on Token.deployed(). Thanks!